# Why is my SVG path unexpectedly clipped in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox?

Tags: svg

Consider the following SVG image code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <title>Clipped Path Problem Demo</title>
    <g id="group:image">
        <defs>
            <mask id="mask">
                <rect id="rectangle:inset" x="250" y="134" width="500" height="732" fill="white"/>
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <g id="group:curves" mask="url('#mask')">
            <!-- <rect id="rectangle:filler.shape" width="1" height="1" fill="transparent"/> -->
            <path id="path:curves" d="
                M 441 327
                c -85 88 -85 175 -85 175
                c 0 88 85 175 85 175
                s 90 103 90 103
                c 85 88 85 175 85 175" fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="73"/>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="group:guides">
        <rect id="rectangle:guide.area:inset" x="250" y="134" width="500" height="732" fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="20 10" stroke-width="1"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

(CodePen: https://codepen.io/patrickdark/full/zPEVVg/. (I added a `height="500px"` attribute to the pen to make it more likely to fit on screen.))

The **left** side of the curved path is clipped to a vertical line even though the mask is well over the size needed to contain that portion of the image.

If I insert a shape of any size with non-zero dimensions into the masked `g` element—such as the 1×1 transparent rectangle in the XML comment—the clipped edge is magically unclipped.

I would think this is a bug except that it’s happening in Chrome (62), Edge (41), and Firefox Developer Edition (58 Beta 4). What I would like to know is **why** this seemingly nonsensical clipping is occurring.

(Note: Clipping at the bottom of the curved path is intentional.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a mask works on color and alpha channel values (a potentially costly operation), it doesn't stretch to infinity, but rendering is clipped of by default at the object bounding box **of the masked element** plus 10% in every direction (defined by the attributes `x, y, width, height` in bounding box units).

The object bounding box although is defined not to include stroke widths. You are surpassing these limits and need to make adjustments at least to the `x` and `width` attribute of the mask.

Since this seems to be not intuitive, the general algorithm for applying a mask goes like this:

1. Identify the region the mask is applied to. This is always the rectangle given by the `x, y, width, height` attributes of the `<mask>` element. If, as is the default, the `maskUnits` attribute is given as [objectBoundingBox](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#ObjectBoundingBoxUnits), the coordinates are determined by the [object bounding box](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#TermObjectBoundingBox) of the element the mask is applied to. The contents of the mask are **not** taken into account. 0 and 1 in that coordinate system are the minimum and maximum of the joined bounding box of the masked element and all its descendants.
2. Superimpose the content of the mask element with the element it is applied to. As a default, the coordinate system used for placing these elements is given as `maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`, which means the same coordinate system the masked element is drawn into.
3. For every point within the region defined above, multiply the opacity of the masked content with the luminance of the masking content to compute a resulting opacity of the masked element.

   ```html
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
       <title>Clipped Path Problem Resoved</title>
       <g id="group:image">
           <defs>
               <mask id="mask" x="-20%" width="140%">
                   <rect id="rectangle:inset" x="250" y="134" width="500" height="732" fill="white"/>
               </mask>
           </defs>
           <g id="group:curves"mask="url('#mask')">
               <!-- <rect id="rectangle:filler.shape" width="1" height="1" fill="transparent"/> -->
               <path id="path:curves" d="
                   M 441 327
                   c -85 88 -85 175 -85 175
                   c 0 88 85 175 85 175
                   s 90 103 90 103
                   c 85 88 85 175 85 175" fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="73"/>
           </g>
       </g>
       <g id="group:guides">
           <rect id="rectangle:guide.area:inset" x="250" y="134" width="500" height="732" fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="20 10" stroke-width="1"/>
       </g>
   </svg>
   ```

Comment: Thanks. So the problem is that the width of the path is 260 units and only its fill box is considered by the mask. With the default -10% mask inset, the mask paints 26 units outside of the fill box, which isn't enough to accommodate the 36.5 units (50%) of the stroke outside of the fill box. I need a mask inset of -14.039% (0 - 36.5 ÷ 260) and width of 128.078% (1 + 36.5 ÷ 260 * 2) to accommodate the stroke.

Comment: The filler shape solves the problem because it modifies the object bounding box in setting the top-left coordinate to 0,0. This appears to be the only strategy for accommodating strokes that are part of the mask (as opposed to the masked content) and not located at the outer bounds of the mask. (A mask appears to iterate over its constituent shapes and apply a -10% inset to each separately, so there can be clipping in the middle of a mask…) If the stroke is on a composite shape created from a symbol, the filler shape apparently needs to be placed inside of the symbol. Talk about unintuitive…

Comment: I am not sure I have understood your comment completely, but there may be a misunderstanding. I've extended the answer.

Comment: My first comment was simply expounding on my understanding of your solution. You appear to have picked arbitrary numbers in 20% and 140% and I prefer precision, so I calculated the exact minimum mask bounds.

Comment: My second comment may be better explained with another pen: https://codepen.io/patrickdark/pen/oopmzw. Remove the `#rectangle:bounding.box.adjustment` element to see clipping in the *middle* of the mask output. No combination of attributes on the `mask` element helped, but adding a filler shape with the intent of resizing the object bounding box did. This seems to contradict your revised answer in which you state "contents of the mask are not taken into account". Apparently, the mask is applied iteratively over each of its content shapes and transparent content can be used to modify behavior.

Comment: So, there may be some browser-specific issue here since the CodePen image I just linked to is simply a black rounded rectangle in Chrome 62 and Edge 41. My initial testing was done in Firefox Developer Edition 58 Beta 4 where the image displays as expected. Looks like something I'll need to investigate.

Comment: Fixed. The problem was that I copied the version of the source code with CSS4 Color HSL color values; Chrome and Edge only support CSS3 HSL color values. The CodePen demo now behaves the same in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox.